# Rails redirect_to choice page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, routes, multiple-choice

In my rails app, I have a student model, and a material_student. Just after the student login, I would redirect it on a page that give him the choice to select between two "edit" views. First is provided by student_controller to manage is personal data and other one is provided by material_student_controller to select some material.

I'm unable to find :

1) the correct route in routes.rb

routes.rb

```
resources :students do

  get 'dashboard' => 'dashboard#index'

end
```

2) the correct "redirect_to" in session_controller to call the dashboard

sessions_controller.rb

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    login from omniauth blahblahblah
    redirect_to :controller => 'dashboard', :action => 'index', :id => user.as_user_id
  end
end
```

The choice page is called "dashboard" and is provided by a dashboard_controller

```
class DashboardController < ApplicationController

  def index

  end

end
```

Could you help me ?

Many thanks in advance

Nicolas

Comment: paste your rake routes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In routes.rb

```
resources :students
resources :dashboard, :only => [:index]
```

In action

```
redirect_to dashboard_path
```

Comment: Many thanks ! I'm stuck with this from days...you are the best ! and i'm really newbies, too !!!!

Comment: you're welcome, please vote up the answer if you found it helpful! :)